# How to edit record in google datastore in AppEngine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, gql

I was create one app which have model and it was created but i facing problem how to edit data in google data store using python or Django. Please Help me.

Comment: Please provide some information on what you have tried so far. What has your problem-solving process been?

Comment: @sagar r u using google cloud sql ??

Comment: @PriyankPatel No i was used free provided google database and use gql(google query language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the record you want to edit (by key , id or any filter) , modify the field you want to edit and then put() it.